# Repeating HAVE twice in one sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, auxiliary-verbs, repetition

I was wondering which one of these sentences is correct:

> I am happy to have successfully completed the certification course by the Chamber of Commerce and acquired a certification in XYZ.

or

> I am happy to **have** successfully completed the certification course by the Chamber of Commerce and **have** acquired a certification in XYZ.

I've read in one of the threads that it's not necessary to repeat auxiliary verb but the examples there were also of less shorter sentences. In my first example it feels like the second have is missing.

Comment: I think you are correct. The sentence is too long to omit the second "have". It just doesn't read well at all - in fact IMHO, it's quite awkward. I would definitely repeat the verb "have".

Comment: Quick tip:  When writing a compound sentence where you want to share the verb, put the wordiest phrase last, not first like you have done.  *I am happy to have acquired a certification and successfully completed......*  The sentence, however, reads best without a second *have*.  Try  *I am happy to have acquired a certification **by** successfully complet**ing**......*

Answer (score 1):

The last few words have different meanings in the two sentences. The first sentence says "I am happy to have ... acquired a certification." The second says "I ... have acquired a certification." In other words the first says you are happy about it and the second just says you acquired it.

Another possibility would be "I am happy to have successfully ... and to have acquired a certification." This has the same meaning as the first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use **have** at all.

I think it's assumed you would be happy that you completed the course. It's probably more typical to relate happiness to *announcing* the achievement rather than simply achieving it. For example:

> I'm happy to announce that I was awarded a certification in XYZ by the Chamber of Commerce after completing their certification course.

Otherwise, I might say something like this:

> I successfully completed the certification course by the Chamber of Commerce and earned a certification in XYZ.

or

> I earned a certification in XYZ by completing the Chamber of Commerce's certification course.